# How can I set default value in serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have these serializers:

```
>---id = serializers.IntegerField()
>---name = serializers.CharField()
>---age = serializers.IntegerField()
```

Now, I give the serializers this data:

```
{'id': 1, 'name': 'cc'}
```

I don't give a value for `age`.
how can I set a default value to `age` in the serializers?

I want to get this, where the `12` is a default value:

```
{'id': 1, 'name': 'cc', 'age': 12}
```

Comment: You need to be specific, what kind of serializer is it (modelserializer or plain serializer?)

Can you show full serializer definition? also if model serializer show model definetion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you make a model field blank, you can set a default value that will be filled in if you don't supply a value on the `POST`:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=42)
                             #^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then, when you `POST` use `{}` as the data

Comment: [Yeah, this is the x-y problem space.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Answer (score 22):

```
age = serializers.IntegerField(default=12, initial=12)
```

initial to pre populate html form. 
See the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments)

Comment: it give me error    `KeyError: u"Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `age` on serializer `OverViewSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: u'age'."`

Comment: @nataila can you update your question with your serializer code..? I was expecting that you are inheriting for ModelSerializer and "age" is Also a field in related model.

Comment: @nataila in that case You need to be a little more specific about what you are trying to do and provide some code... :)

Answer (score 18):

do you want to set in serializers?

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   age = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   def get_age(self, obj):
       return getattr(obj, 'age', 12)

   class Meta:
       model = Person
       field = ('id', 'name', 'age')
```

Answer (score 15):

As you said, you don't have a model

1.serializer.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    age = serializers.IntegerField(default=12) #if key age is missing, value of age become 12

    def validate(self,data):
        #other wise you can set default value of age here,
        if data.get('age',None)==None: #this conditon will be true only when age = serializer.IntergerField(required=False)
            data['age']=12
        return data
```

views.py

```
serializer = UserSerializer(data={'id': 1, 'name': 'cc', 'age': 14})
serializer.is_valid()
# True
serializer.validated_data
# {'id': 1, 'name': 'cc', 'age': 14}
```

or if you miss specifying age in views.py

```
serializer = UserSerializer(data={'id': 1, 'name': 'cc'})
serializer.is_valid()
# True
serializer.validated_data
# {'id': 1, 'name': 'cc', 'age': 12}
```

Hope this help someone :)

Comment: This works but it's probably preferable to use a SerializerMethodField so you don't have to override validate.Also it's advised to use `is` over `==` when doing a comparison against none