# Django Rest Framework ignores default value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Any idea why does Django Rest Framework ignore default values?

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(default='Yes')

class MyClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyCLass
        fields = ['some_field']

class MyClassListCreateAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = MyClass.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyClassSerializer
```

When I send `{'some_field': None}` /null/something like this. I always get:

```
Bad Request: /myurl/
[02/Dec/2022 16:44:59] "POST /myurl/ HTTP/1.1" 400 114
```

When changed to:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
        some_field = models.CharField(default='Yes', blank=True, null=True)
```

it works but always sets the `NULL` value.
Is this expected behaviour? Should I change the mechanics of my POST request to include changing value to default when user doesn't provide one?

Comment: Have you tried `class MyClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):` `some_field = serializers.CharField(default='Yes')` ? See here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215566/how-can-i-set-default-value-in-serializers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a minor misconception.

Posting `{'some_field': None}` to your API is informing your Serializer to manufacture a `MyClass` instance with `some_field` set to `None`- not to use the default. It is not using the default value- because you're instantiating it with a value of `None`.

If you want to use the `default` value on your model- you need to clean/remove the `some_field` value during serializer Validation so that the `create()` call does not have this field present- and the default will be used.

> Should I change the mechanics of my POST request to include changing value to default when user doesn't provide one?

This would certainly be *a* solution and would work. But unless this is well documented- outside consumers of your API may notice the same odd behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is the main problem but: are you setting the `max_length` required option in your MyClass model definition?
If it's not needed, why it's not required in this case? In the [fields types' documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#charfield) is supposed to be required.